# Text mesh pro moving issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
public class spawningunits : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public static int amount1 = 100;
    public static int amount2 = 200;
    public GameObject ShadowWolf;
    public GameObject Cannibal;
    //public GameObject numberofunits1;
    //public GameObject numberofunits2;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject numberofunits1;
    [SerializeField] private TMP_Text numberofunits2;
    GameObject someObj;
    
    
    
    
    private void Start(){
        
        
        
        //numberofunits1.text = "200";
        numberofunits2.text = "600";
        Instantiate(numberofunits1, new Vector3(50, -1, -5), Quaternion.identity);
        Instantiate(numberofunits2, new Vector3(45, -1, -5), Quaternion.identity);
        
        Instantiate(ShadowWolf, new Vector3(56, -1, -5), Quaternion.identity);
        ShadowWolf.SetActive(true);
        Instantiate(Cannibal, new Vector3(-56, -1, -5), Quaternion.identity);
        Cannibal.SetActive(true);

        someObj = new GameObject("SomeObj");
        numberofunits1.transform.parent = someObj.transform;
        
        //GameObject someObj = new GameObject("SomeObj");
        //someObj.AddComponent(numberofunits1);
        
        //Vector3 pozycjacannibala = Cannibal.transform.position;
        //Vector3 pozycjashadowwolfa = ShadowWolf.transform.position;
        //numberofunits1.text = "200";
        numberofunits2.text = "100";
        
        
    }
    void Update() {
        
        
        
        //GameObject someObj = new GameObject("SomeObj");
        //numberofunits1.transform.parent = someObj;
        //Gameobject numberofunits1g = Gameobject.Find("numberofunits1g").GetComponent<GameObject>();
        //Vector3 pozycjacannibala = Cannibal.transform.position;
        //Vector3 pozycjashadowwolfa = ShadowWolf.transform.position;
        
        //numberofunits1.transform.position = new Vector3(20,-1,-5);
        numberofunits2.transform.position = new Vector3(Cannibal.transform.position.x,Cannibal.transform.position.y,Cannibal.transform.position.z);
        numberofunits2.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition += new Vector3(20,-1,-5);
        //numberofunits1.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = new Vector3(-56,-1,-5);
        //Vector3 poz = numberofunits1.transform.position;
        //print(poz);
        someObj.transform.position = new Vector3(Cannibal.transform.position.x,Cannibal.transform.position.y,Cannibal.transform.position.z);
        //numberofunits1.transform.position = new Vector3(40, 12, -5);
        //numberofunits1.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(20,-1);
        //Vector3 poz = numberofunits1.transform.position;
        
        //print(poz);
        
        
        
        
        
        
                
                
        
    }
}
```

What I want to do is move text to a certain position (the text is a prefab, I'm using text mesh pro). The problem I get is that instantiation works correctly setting up the text in a desired position, however I cant seem to be able to move it later on. The code doesn't throw any errors and I even set a print function to see what position does the code display and the position is correct, but on the screen the text is still in the same place. The project is being created in 2d.

Comment: Im guessing it works but you cannot see the start positioning because it lasts half a frame. In the update, run the positioning code in Input.GetKeyDown so it requires a press to move.

Comment: On second thought, also you are setting the prefab. The created items are not stored and likely not under a canvas so they wont show

Comment: Yeah well but the problem is that they do show, but dont change their position.

Comment: I think you're seeing the original object, Instantiate is not placing the new object anywhere so you have no connection to it. NumberofUnits1 is the original obj you are duplicating and placing.

Answer (score 2):

When moving UI elements you will need to use the RectTransform instead of the regular transform (however the regular transform will still work for world space ui).

For example you could use:
numberofunits1.GetComponent().anchoredPosition = new Vector2(20,-1);

if you really need the z position you can use:
numberofunits1.GetComponent().anchoredPosition3D = new Vector3(20,-1,-5);

You can find the documentation on RectTransform here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.html

I also recommend using the TextMeshPro variable for the UI element you are trying to use. So in this case: TMP_Text.

So your variable declaration would become:
[SerializeField] private TMP_Text numberofunits1;
[SerializeField] private TMP_Text numberofunits2;

If you're trying to move the full set of UI it might be useful if you move the regular transform on the Canvas. However in that case the canvas needs to be World Space.

Comment: I changed variables as u suggested but using the code with anchored position throws an error :                 The type arguments for method 'Component.GetComponent<T>()' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.                   I've also tried using numberofunits1.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(20,-1); but it throws error as well :        'TMP_Text' does not contain a definition for 'anchoredPosition' and no accessible extension method 'anchoredPosition' accepting a first argument of type 'TMP_Text' could be found

Comment: anchoredPosition is a method that only exists in the component RectTransform so that's why it didn't work with the second thing you tried.

However I don't understand why GetComponent didn't work. Do you have a demo-project perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

TextMeshPro doesn't contain transform component but rect transform so you need to chanage rect trasnform Or you can either create a gameObject like

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject numberofunits1;
[SerializeField] private GameObject numberofunits2;

GameObject someObj;    
void Start(){
   someObj = new GameObject("SomeObj");
   numberofunits1.transform.parent = someObj;
}


void Update() 
{
    numberofunits1.text = "200";
    numberofunits2.text = "100";
    //Gameobject numberofunits1g = Gameobject.Find("numberofunits1g").GetComponent<GameObject>();
    //Vector3 pozycjacannibala = Cannibal.transform.position;
    //Vector3 pozycjashadowwolfa = ShadowWolf.transform.position;
    
    numberofunits2.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition += new Vector3(20,-1,-5) * Time.deltTime;
    someObj.transform.position += new Vector3(Cannibal.transform.position.x,Cannibal.transform.position.y,Cannibal.transform.position.z) * Time.deltaTime;
    Vector3 poz = numberofunits1.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition.transform.position;
    print(poz);
}
```

Comment: I've tried above code but first two lines throw up an error Assets\scripts\spawningunits.cs(33,24): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'TMPro.TMP_Text' to 'System.Type'

Comment: How do I change to rect transform?

Comment: Change it by either += new Vector 3 as you change vector on any game object

Comment: Wait so should I go with: numberofunits1.transform.position += new Vector3(20,-1,-5);  ???

Comment: numberofunits1.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition += new Vector3(20,-1,-5) * Time.deltaime;

Comment: The code actually works without errors, but text is still in the same place :( However when I print out the position it looks like its changing, but the text is still at the same spot.

Comment: try to assign text to parent gameObject I have edited the code and change the position of the parent gameObject

Comment: Hmm those two lines of code GameObject someObj = new GameObject("SomeObj");
numberofunits1.transform.parent = someObj; cause a following error Assets\scripts\spawningunits.cs(24,37): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'UnityEngine.Transform'

Comment: Because you are attaching a component to a gameobject make numberofunits1 a gameobject you have initilized it as TextMeshPro make it a GameObject

Comment: But how do I change it I tried and deleted intitailizing as textmeshpro but it still does not work. Could you please show the code that I'm supoposed to have .

Comment: I have edit the code cannot write the whole code.

Comment: Okay I edited the code, this is what I have, it still throws an error : Assets\scripts\spawningunits.cs(17,34): error CS1519: Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: Can you share the screen shot?

Comment: Yeah sure, I can but I mean I edited the post so that You can see the whole code, think it should have updated but maybe Im wrong.

Comment: You have to initilize new GameObject with in start or constructor. I have edited the code look once and try

Comment: I have edited it once more so that you can see but then It throws the same error in line 36 :  Assets\scripts\spawningunits.cs(36,40): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'UnityEngine.Transform'

Comment: do it like this:   numberofunits1.transform.parent = someObj.transform;

Comment: Oh now It doesnt throw up any errors nut when I hit play it says:  Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a Prefab Asset is disabled to prevent data corruption (GameObject: 'numberofunits').
UnityEngine.Transform:set_parent (UnityEngine.Transform)
spawningunits:Start () (at Assets/scripts/spawningunits.cs:36)

Comment: Have you assigned the gameobject numberofunits to script from inspector?

Comment: Yes I did assign it.

Comment: Dont know if this matters but the prefab name is numberofunits. I dont know if this changes anything.

Comment: Apply this once 

   numberofunits1.transform.parent = someObj.transform;

   in place of

   numberofunits1.transform.parent = someObj;

Comment: I applied this but still throws the same: Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a Prefab Asset is disabled to prevent data corruption (GameObject: 'numberofunits').
UnityEngine.Transform:set_parent (UnityEngine.Transform)
spawningunits:Start () (at Assets/scripts/spawningunits.cs:36)

Comment: If you want a screen share can join meeting with link below
https://meet.google.com/igb-apxn-tbe

Comment: What about discord, u can give me your username and I'll invite u ?

Comment: Sure Mariana44#3858

Comment: I've sent an invitation, my nickname is khukabs.